# How to implement Algolia in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, algolia

I am just starting to dive into the Algolia world. There are many things that I do not quite understand. I have a task to implement Algolia in a web app. The web app is using Express + GraphQL on the backend and React on the front. Also, as the persistence layer, the app is using Postgresql. I think I have a good grasp of what needs to be done on the front, but not on the back. More specifically, I do not understand how to push data from my backend to Algolia.

Should I first query my data and then feed it to `index.addObjects`? If so, how then I programmatically and periodically run this “push” script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building an app using Algolia requires several steps.
First you need to upload your data using [`addObjects`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/getting-started/quick-start-with-the-api-client/javascript/?language=javascript#push-data). Then you need to configure your index with the dashboard. And then you should build your UI. For that purpose, there is a library called react-instantsearch that makes creating search UI easy.

Finally you want to keep your data in sync, and for that you should implement a slightly different version of your initial import that pushes the data as they are updated in your database. Ideally it should only update the differences.

Comment: It would be great to have an example of the setup that you explained above.

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/importing-data/importing-with-the-api/